# How to get label text that is changed with jquery inside gridview from code behind

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, .net, c#-5.0

Currently the code behind label control is giving me a null value when i submit the form. How can i add the value to a local variable?

Please advise.

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".chk").change(function () {
        var total = 0;
        var chks = $(".chk input:checked");
        if (chks.length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < chks.length; i++) {
                total += parseFloat($("#" + chks[i].id.replace("courseID", "lblcoursePrice")).html());
                $("#<%=courseListView.ClientID %> [id*=hfTotal]").val("");
            }
        }

        $("#<%=courseListView.ClientID %> [id*=lblTotal]").text(total.toFixed(2));
        $("#<%=courseListView.ClientID %> [id*=hfTotal]").val($(this).val());
    });
});
```

.NET PAGE

```
<asp:GridView ID="courseListView" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server" ShowFooter="true">
                                        <Columns>
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" />
                                            <asp:TemplateField>
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="courseID" class="chk" runat="server" />
                                                   <asp:Label ID="courseTitle" Text='<%# Eval("name") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                                <FooterTemplate>
                                                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" Text="Total" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                                </FooterTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Price">
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:Label ID="lblcoursePrice" Text='<%# Eval("price") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                                <FooterTemplate>
                                                    <asp:Label ID="lblTotal" Text="" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hfTotal" runat="server" />
                                                </FooterTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateField>

                                        </Columns>
                                    </asp:GridView>
```

CODE BEHIND

```
 Label courseAmount = (Label)FindControl("lblTotal");
    if (courseAmount != null)
    {
        course = courseAmount.Text; //courseButtonList.SelectedValue;
    }
```

Comment: Two things: be more careful with your tags (this is clearly not MVC code), and note that JavaScript is most certainly *not* Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I cannot see where you are trying to find this Label control. I'll give you options.

**First :** In Page Load or some other function

```
Label courseAmount = (Label)courseListView.Rows[0].Cells[0].FindControl("lblTotal");
```

**Second :** In `courseListView_RowDataBound` you can call like:

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) 
{ 
    Label lbl= (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblTotal"); 
}
```

**Third :**

```
protected void courseListView_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow valu = (GridViewRow)((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer;
    int RowIndex = valu.RowIndex;
    Label value = (Label)courseListView.Rows[RowIndex].FindControl("lblTotal");
    string course = value.Text;
}
```